# String assignment in C#

Tags: c#, string, reference, heap-memory

A few weeks ago, I discovered that strings in C# are defined as reference types and not value types. Initially I was confused about this, but then after some reading, I suddenly understood why it is important to store strings on the heap and not the stack - because it would be very inefficient to have a very large string that gets copied over an unpredictable number of stack frames. I completely accept this.

I feel that my understanding is almost complete, but there is one element that I am missing - what language feature do strings use to keep them immutable? To illustrate with a code example:

```
string valueA = "FirstValue";
string valueB = valueA;
valueA = "AnotherValue";

Assert.AreEqual("FirstValue", valueB); // Passes
```

I do not understand what language feature makes a copy of valueA when I assign it to valueB. Or perhaps, the reference to valueA does not change when I assign it to valueB, only valueA gets a new reference to itself when I set the string. As this is an instance type, I do not understand why this works.

I understand that you can overload, for example, the == and != operators, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on overloading the = operators. What is the explanation?

Comment: Of course you're talking about language feature, but immutability isn't the correct term here (it's just about the class, as Jason says). In C# assignments are done by copying the reference, not assigning the reference itself. May be you should see this too: [c-sharp-reference-assignment-operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844791/c-sharp-reference-assignment-operator)

Comment: I like to read it as if it was doing this,                                                    `string valueA = new String("FirstValue");`
`string valueB = valueA;`
`valueA = new String("AnotherValue");`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> what language feature do strings use to keep them immutable?

It is not a language feature. It is the way the class is defined.

For example,

```
class Integer {
    private readonly int value;

    public int Value { get { return this.value; } }
    public Integer(int value) { this.value = value; } }
    public Integer Add(Integer other) {
        return new Integer(this.value + other.value);
    }
}
```

is like an `int` except it's a reference type, but it's immutable. We *defined* it to be so. We can define it to be mutable too:

```
class MutableInteger {
    private int value;

    public int Value { get { return this.value; } }
    public MutableInteger(int value) { this.value = value; } }
    public MutableInteger Add(MutableInteger other) {
        this.value = this.value + other.value;
        return this;
    } 
}
```

See?

> I do not understand what language feature makes a copy of `valueA` when I assign it to `valueB`.

It doesn't copy the `string`, it copies the reference. `string`s are reference type. This means that variables of type `string`s are storage locations whose values are references. In this case, their values are references to instances of `string`. When you assign a variable of type `string` to another of type `string`, the value is copied. In this case, the value is a reference and it is copied by the assignment. This is true for any reference type, not just `string` or only immutable reference types.

> Or perhaps, the reference to `valueA` does not change when I assign it to `valueB`, only `valueA` gets a new reference to itself when i set the string.

Nope, the values of `valueA` and `valueB` refer to the same instance of `string`. Their values are references, and those values are equal. If you could somehow mutate<sup>*</sup> the instance of `string` referred to by `valueA`, the referrent of both `valueA` and `valueB` would see this mutation.

> As this is an instance type, I do not understand why this works.

There is no such thing as an instance type.

Basically, `string`s are reference types. But `string` are immutable. When you mutate a `string`, what happens is that you get a reference to a new string that is the result of the mutation to the already existing `string`.

```
string s = "hello, world!";
string t = s;
string u = s.ToUpper();
```

Here, `s` and `t` are variables whose values refer to the same instance of `string`. The referrent of `s` is not mutated by the call to `String.ToUpper`. Instead, `s.ToUpper` makes a mutation of the referrent of `s` and returns a reference to a new instance of `string` that it creates in the process of apply the mutation. We assign that reference to `u`.

> I understand that you can overload, for example, the == and != operators, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on overloading the = operators.

You can't overload `=`.

<sup>*</sup> You can, with some tricks. Ignore them.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your example will work the same to any reference variables, not just strings.

What happens is:

```
string valueA = "FirstValue"; //ValueA is referenced to "FirstValue"  
string valueB = valueA; //valueB references to what valueA is referenced to which is "FirstValue"  
valueA = "AnotherValue"; //valueA now references a new value: "AnotherValue"
Assert.AreEqual("FirstValue", valueB); // remember that valueB references "FirstValue"
```

Now the [**immutability**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is a different concept. It means that the value itself can't be changed.
This will show up in a situation like this:

```
string valueA = "FirstValue"; //ValueA is referenced to "FirstValue"  
string valueB = valueA; //valueB references to what valueA is referenced to which is "FirstValue"  
valueA.Replace('F','B'); //valueA will now be: "BirstValue"
Assert.AreEqual("FirstValue", valueB); // remember that valueB references "FirstValue"
```

This is because of String's immutability, valueA doesn't change the string itself... It creates a new **COPY** with the changes and references that.

Comment: While your answer explains the first part well, your point on immutability is not very correct. `valueA.Replace('F', 'B')` will leave `valueA` with "FirstValue" still, that's how immutable they are.

Comment: string.Replace(this string, char, char) literally returns a new string as a return value.  I'm not sure that the second example above, demonstrates immutability, because the return value is not used in the assertion.  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: I think he meant valueA = valueA.Replace('F','B');

Answer (score 4):

> Or perhaps, the reference to valueA
>   does not change when I assign it to
>   valueB, only valueA gets a new
>   reference to itself when i set the
>   string.

That is correct. As strings are immutable, there is no problem having two variables referencing the same string object. When you assign a new string to one of them, it's the reference that is replaced, not the string object.

> I cannot seem to find any
>   documentation on overloading the =
>   operators.

That is not due to any shortcoming on your side, it's because there is no way to overload the assignment operator in C#.

The `=` operator is quite simple, it takes the value on the right hand side and assigns to the variable on the left hand side. If it's a reference type, the value is the reference, so that is what's assigned.