# Modify an object in multiple layers of classes

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I have an application with the following:

1. A data layer class containing the data handling logic and the data itself.

> ```
> public class DataLayer_JSON
> {
>     CacheData chd = new CacheData();
>     //The chd object contains the actual data used in the DataLayer_JSON class
>
>    public DataLayer_JSON(string relPath) }
> ```

2. A main menu form (essentially it could be just any class)

> ```
>  public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
> {
>     DataLayer_JSON data = new DataLayer_JSON("questions.txt");
>     ...
>     private void btnEditon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>     ...
>         using (var EF = new EditorForm(data.GetCathegories(), data.GetDifficulties(), data.GetQuestions()))
>         {
>             var result = EF.ShowDialog();
>             if(result == DialogResult.OK)
>             {
>                 data.ClearQuestions();  //Clear all cached questions
>                 //Since we are still in scope of the EditorForm (EF) within the using clause, we can access it's members
>                 data.AddQuestionRange(EF.AllQuestions); //Replace cache with the edited list
>             }
>         }
>         ...
>          //Here we save the data permanently to a text file when closing the program. 
>          //This could also be done from the EditorForm if we wanted to
>          private void MainMenuForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
>     {
>         data.Save("questions.txt");
>     }
> ```

3. An editor form (started from #2)

> `public EditorForm(IEnumerable<INameObject> Cathegories, IEnumerable<INameObject> Difficulties, IEnumerable<Question> oldQuestions)
>           {
>           ...
>           }`

In #2, I create and initialize the data layer instance (#1). I want to modify the data contained in #1 from within #3, but so far, I have only been able to pass by value the contents from #1 to #3, via #2. The results are then returned from #3 to #2 and handled there.

I've read about passing by reference in C#, but my conclusion is that you cant assign a variable to the reference, and then have that variable modify the original data.

I read about the references in C# in the following places this time, as well as reading extensively about this topic many times before:
[C# reference assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844791/c-sharp-reference-assignment-operator) [How do I assign by "reference" to a class field in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980463/how-do-i-assign-by-reference-to-a-class-field-in-c/)

So the question is:
How can I go about changing the content of an instance of #1 directly in #3?

Comment: Make #1 static, thus exposing it to #2 and #3. Keep it read-only to avoid blaspheming the C# gods.

Comment: We need to see example code here. By default, if you pass an instance of a class somewhere, you are passing a reference.

Comment: Agree with @Blorgbeard ... I have something in my head (like read-only concurrent collections that are threadsafe as static) but your code may not be anything like that, thereby rendering my earlier advice moot or even bad.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go about changing the content of an instance of #1 directly in #3?

Well, you'd start by passing the instance of #1 to #3. Currently you are not doing that.

So for example:

```
public EditorForm(DataLayer_Json data)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
using (var EF = new EditorForm(data))
```

Then inside the `EditorForm`, you can do whatever you want to `data` (*except* for reassigning the actual reference) and those changes will be reflected outside of `EditorForm` as well.

```
data.ClearQuestions();          // Works fine, mutating the object.
data = new DataLayer_JSON();    // Doesn't affect the `data` variable that was passed in.
```